# Get running service daemon in C on specific port?

Tags: c, linux, service, daemon

I've to get the daemon (and perhaps the version of it) that works in a specific port received from input. Something like "22" -> "SSH".

How can I do ?

Comment: What?  People here are helpful but not clairvoyant.  Please edit your question into something approaching an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <netdb.h>

char servname[50];
struct addrinfo *ai;
getaddrinfo(0, "22", 0, &ai);
getnameinfo(ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen, 0, 0, servname, sizeof servname, 0);
freeaddrinfo(ai);
```

Note: This code is incomplete. You should check for errors, and if your port number is originally an integer and not a string, you can use `snprintf` to make a decimal string to pass to `getaddrinfo`.

Unlike the old `getservbyport()` interface, the solution I've given is thread-safe and clean to call from library code.

Comment: I think there's a problem: getnameinfo give me, on 22 or other, the name of service (like "ssh", or "ftp"..) but I need the real name of service in use and the version, like OpenSSH_5.2p1, somethink like "ssh -version" command or other for another service.

Comment: Then you need to connect to the port and use whatever protocol-specific method to request the server's name. Of course there's no guarantee that the server will be willing to tell you its name (and arguably, good ones shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you just want to look the port up in the local service database (if so, use [R's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390318/get-running-service-daemon-in-c-on-specific-port/4390506#4390506)), or whether you want to actively examine the port to attempt to determine the listening service.

If it's the latter, then the best way is probably to just run [`nmap`](http://www.nmap.org/) against the local port of interest.

Comment: I think OP is trying to write his own `nmap` or perhaps trying to extend some existing exploit script to check for known-vulnerable servers...